# PL/SQL: Member of method with "where"

Tags: plsql, memberof

How could I do this:

Select values from three different columns into nested table or some other kind of collection...

```
DECLARE
TYPE blockers_set IS TABLE OF (
employee_ID NUMBER(8), 
BLOCKING_GROUP NUMBER(4),
BLOCKING_TYPE NUMBER2(2));

select employee_ID, BLOCKING_GROUP, BLOCKING_TYPE 
bulk collect into blockers
from blockers;
```

...and refer to columns:

```
if employee_ID not member of blockers where blocking_group = 1
and blocking_type = 2
then <<business logic>>
```

There can be more than one row for one employee_ID in blockers-collection.

This is has to be done with pl/sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE blockers(
                        employee_id NUMBER(8),
                        blocking_group NUMBER(4),
                        blocking_type number(2));


===============================

select * from blockers;

===============================

Create or replace type OBJ_BLOCKERS as OBJECT(
                                                employee_id NUMBER(8),
                                                blocking_group NUMBER(4),
                                                blocking_type number(2)
                                            );

=================================================

Create or replace type varble is table of OBJ_BLOCKERS;

===================================================

DECLARE
  --Creating one element for comparision. In your case you need to populate your employee_id to be compared here.    
  tmp OBJ_BLOCKERS:=OBJ_BLOCKERS(263427,1,2);
  var  varble;
  myid INT;

begin

  --This how you Select values from three different columns into nested table(Object)
  Select OBJ_BLOCKERS(employee_id,
                      blocking_group,
                      blocking_type) 
  Bulk Collect into var
  from blockers;

  -- Displaying Employee_Id from the collection
  For i in 1..var.count
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(var(i).employee_id);
  end loop;

  --

  SELECT  1
        INTO    myid
        FROM    TABLE(var) q
        where  OBJ_BLOCKERS(q.employee_id,q.blocking_group,q.blocking_type) = tmp --Here you are comparing the employee_id which should be a member of collection
        AND q.blocking_group = 1;

  IF (myid = 1) THEN
       dbms_output.put_line('OK, exists.');
  END IF;       

 Exception
 When No_DATa_found then
        dbms_output.put_line('No Data Found');  

End;
```

Execution:

```
SQL> /
263427
534366
454562
OK, exists.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Note that:

> if employee_ID not member of blockers where blocking_group = 1 and
>   blocking_type = 2

This is not possible using a `Member Funtion`. You need to declare a `MAP` method, which is rather clunky and would get rather annoying if the object has a lot of attributes(just like your case).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That seems workable. I'll try that.

Would it be possible somehow to use one query to bulk collect into different types... with case?

    Select case 
when employee_ID = 1 then bulk collect into blocker1
when employee_ID = 2 then bulk collect into blocker2
end

I couldn't get it right.

@XING

Comment: @PLPertti.. you are asking this to me or tell me ? I couldnot understand

Comment: What I am trying to ask: is this possible to be done in one query:

select blocker bulk collect into blocker_1 
from blockers 
where blocker_type =1;

select blocker bulk collect into blocker_2 
from blockers 
where blocker_type =2;

@XING

Comment: No this is not possible. You cannot select from the collection.

Comment: but if "blockers" is a table, not collection? @XING

Comment: I dont think its possible the way you are asking. You can try if that works for you